# Meaning of timekeeper and oriented

Tags: geography

What is the meaning of oriented and timekeeper in below sentence.

> From google: Timekeeper means one who records the time in sports. and
> oriented means positioned or faces towards

but could not understand it in below context. Can you explain it in simple speech?

Our global time system is oriented to the Sun. The relationship between sun and earth is considered as the best time keeper in the world.

Source of information is below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What they are saying is We base our time as a society (when to go to work, eat, sleep) on the cycle of the sun.  sunrise, noon, sunset.

Comment: `Our global time system is oriented to the Sun`, can you please explain it in simple speech?

Comment: global time system is we go to work in the day, we sleep at night, etc.  we decide when it is day and night by using the sun

Comment: Can you explain this sentence in details: `The relationship between sun and earth is considered as the best time keeper in the world.`?

Answer (score 0):

Louis Essen built the first Cesium clock in 1955. That's an atomic clock so accurate that it doesn't lose time.

Comment: Can you explain this sentence in details: `The relationship between sun and earth is considered as the best time keeper in the world.`?